# Adding additional reference to Bibtex

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I need to add an additional reference to my Bibtex file manually. The format of the reference as stated by the Australian Bureau of Statistics is

> Australian Bureau of Statistics 2011, *Dwelling Characteristics (2011)*, TableBuilder. Findings based on use of ABS TableBuilder data.

(Link: http://www.abs.gov.au/ausstats/abs@.nsf/web+pages/Citing+ABS+Sources#TableBuilder)

I tried to add this using the below entry

```
@misc{ABS2011,
author = {{Australian Bureau of Statistics}},
title = {Dwelling Characteristics (2011)},
publisher= {{TableBuilder. Findings based on use of ABS TableBuilder data}},
year = {2011}
}
```

But I'm unable to get this in the Pdf. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your title says `BibTeX` but you tagged your question with `Biblatex`. Are you using the former or the latter? Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Please provide a MWE

Comment: @Troy Thanks. Its the reference file with .bib extension to generate my Latex document bibliography. I'm a newbie. So not sure which tag I should use

Comment: Do you have a `\cite{ABS2011}` in your LaTeX somewhere? If not, you could put `\nocite{ABS2011}` somewhere (it will include the reference to your bibliography without having to cite it somewhere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have some specific reference in your document, but don't cite it anywhere in your text, you use the `\nocite` macro somewhere in your document. It will add the specific reference to the bibliography without creating a citation.

Full code example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{ABS2011,
author = {Australian Bureau of Statistics},
title = {Dwelling Characteristics},
note = {TableBuilder. Findings based on use of ABS TableBuilder data},
year = {2011}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\nocite{ABS2011}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]